# SSL misdirected with MSM

Tags: multi-site-manager

I'm running into an issue trying to use SSL for a registration form on an MSM set-up.

When viewing pages via https on SITE A, the EE globals/paths are getting set incorrectly to SITE B instead of SITE A. For example:

```
{stylesheet='_css/styles.css'}
```

when viewed securely on SITE A, shows

```
https://SITEB.com/eeindex.php?css=_css/styles.css.v.1354718804
```

and

```
<a href="{path=LOGOUT}">Log Out</a>
```

viewed securely on a page on SITE B shows up as

```
https://SITEB.com/eeindex.php?ACT=10
```

When the page is viewed with just http://, it works fine.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thank you,

Paula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into Admin -> System Administration -> Output and Debugging and turn on the Output Profiler, then look at the config variables displayed there.  If you find one pointing at the wrong place, that is probably the place to look for the culprit.  My best guess would be in the index.php for site a.

Comment: Thanks for getting me started on the right track! Turns out it was the Base Site URL for the CodeIgniter root in /system/expressionengine/config/config.php file.

Comment: I'm very glad you got it sorted out.  If this answer got you there, may I suggest accepting the answer?  To do so you just need to click the little checkbox under the voting arrows.

Comment: Ah, thanks for guiding a Stack Exchange newbie on the process. Done!

Answer (score 0):

Are you logged in when experiencing this problem? Or, put another way, does this problem occur when you are **not** logged in? It appears that EE's `fetch_site_index` method is cached, so the base URL could theoretically be persisting across sites. Just something to try—I haven't thoroughly tested this yet.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Mark. I was logged in when testing before, so just tried in a different browser, not logged in, but the problem persists.